# Play video using mse (media source extension) in google chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, ffmpeg, signalr, media-source

I’m working on a project that convert rtsp stream (ffmpeg) and play it on the web page (signalr + mse).

So far it works pretty much as I expected on the latest version of edge and firefox, but not chrome.

here's the code

```
public class WebmMediaStreamContext
{
    private Process _ffProcess;
    private readonly string _cmd;
    private byte[] _initSegment;
    private Task _readMediaStreamTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    private const string _CmdTemplate = "-i {0} -c:v libvpx -tile-columns 4 -frame-parallel 1 -keyint_min 90 -g 90 -f webm -dash 1 pipe:";

    public static readonly byte[] ClusterStart = { 0x1F, 0x43, 0xB6, 0x75, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

    public event EventHandler<ClusterReadyEventArgs> ClusterReadyEvent;

    public WebmMediaStreamContext(string rtspFeed)
    {
        _cmd = string.Format(_CmdTemplate, rtspFeed);
    }

    public async Task StartConverting()
    {
        if (_ffProcess != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        _ffProcess = new Process();
        _ffProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe",
            Arguments = _cmd,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };
        _ffProcess.Start();

        _initSegment = await ParseInitSegmentAndStartReadMediaStream();
    }

    public byte[] GetInitSegment()
    {
        return _initSegment;
    }

    // Find the first cluster， and everything before it is the InitSegment
    private async Task<byte[]> ParseInitSegmentAndStartReadMediaStream()
    {
        Memory<byte> buffer = new byte[10 * 1024];
        int length = 0;
        while (length != buffer.Length)
        {
            length += await _ffProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer.Slice(length));
            int cluster = buffer.Span.IndexOf(ClusterStart);
            if (cluster >= 0)
            {
                _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                _readMediaStreamTask = new Task(() => ReadMediaStreamProc(buffer.Slice(cluster, length - cluster).ToArray(), _cancellationTokenSource.Token), _cancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                _readMediaStreamTask.Start();
                return buffer.Slice(0, cluster).ToArray();
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    private void ReadMoreBytes(Span<byte> buffer)
    {
        int size = buffer.Length;
        while (size > 0)
        {
            int len = _ffProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer.Slice(buffer.Length - size));
            size -= len;
        }
    }

    // Parse every single cluster and fire ClusterReadyEvent
    private void ReadMediaStreamProc(byte[] bytesRead, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        Span<byte> buffer = new byte[5 * 1024 * 1024];
        bytesRead.CopyTo(buffer);
        int bufferEmptyIndex = bytesRead.Length;

        do
        {
            if (bufferEmptyIndex < ClusterStart.Length + 4)
            {
                ReadMoreBytes(buffer.Slice(bufferEmptyIndex, 1024));
                bufferEmptyIndex += 1024;
            }

            int clusterDataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(
                buffer.Slice(ClusterStart.Length, 4)
                .ToArray()
                .Reverse()
                .ToArray()
            );
            int clusterSize = ClusterStart.Length + 4 + clusterDataSize;
            if (clusterSize > buffer.Length)
            {
                byte[] newBuffer = new byte[clusterSize];
                buffer.Slice(0, bufferEmptyIndex).CopyTo(newBuffer);
                buffer = newBuffer;
            }

            if (bufferEmptyIndex < clusterSize)
            {
                ReadMoreBytes(buffer.Slice(bufferEmptyIndex, clusterSize - bufferEmptyIndex));
                bufferEmptyIndex = clusterSize;
            }

            ClusterReadyEvent?.Invoke(this, new ClusterReadyEventArgs(buffer.Slice(0, bufferEmptyIndex).ToArray()));

            bufferEmptyIndex = 0;
        } while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested);
    }
}
```

I use ffmpeg to convert the rtsp stream to vp8 WEBM byte stream and parse it to "Init Segment" (ebml head、info、tracks...) and "Media Segment" (cluster)， then send it to browser via signalR

```
$(function () {

    var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    var mimeCodec = 'video/webm; codecs="vp8"';

    var video = document.getElementById('video');

    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', callback, false);
    function callback(e) {
        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
        var queue = [];

        sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function () {
            if (queue.length === 0) {
                return;
            }

            var base64 = queue[0];
            if (base64.length === 0) {
                mediaSource.endOfStream();
                queue.shift();
                return;
            } else {
                var buffer = new Uint8Array(atob(base64).split("").map(function (c) {
                    return c.charCodeAt(0);
                }));
                sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
                queue.shift();
            }
        }, false);

        var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/signalr-video")
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .build();
        connection.start().then(function () {
            connection.stream("InitVideoReceive")
                .subscribe({
                    next: function(item) {
                        if (queue.length === 0 && !!!sourceBuffer.updating) {
                            var buffer = new Uint8Array(atob(item).split("").map(function (c) {
                                return c.charCodeAt(0);
                            }));
                            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
                            console.log(blockindex++ + " : " + buffer.byteLength);
                        } else {
                            queue.push(item);
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        queue.push('');
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                });
        });
    }
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
})
```

chrome just play the video for 3~5 seconds and then stop for buffering, even though there are plenty of cluster transfered and inserted into SourceBuffer.

here's the information in chrome://media-internals/

Player Properties:

```
render_id: 217
player_id: 1
origin_url: http://localhost:52531/
frame_url: http://localhost:52531/
frame_title: Home Page
url: blob:http://localhost:52531/dcb25d89-9830-40a5-ba88-33c13b5c03eb
info: Selected FFmpegVideoDecoder for video decoding, config: codec: vp8 format: 1 profile: vp8 coded size: [1280,720] visible rect: [0,0,1280,720] natural size: [1280,720] has extra data? false encryption scheme: Unencrypted rotation: 0°
pipeline_state: kSuspended
found_video_stream: true
video_codec_name: vp8
video_dds: false
video_decoder: FFmpegVideoDecoder
duration: unknown
height: 720
width: 1280
video_buffering_state: BUFFERING_HAVE_NOTHING
for_suspended_start: false
pipeline_buffering_state: BUFFERING_HAVE_NOTHING
event: PAUSE
```

Log

```
Timestamp       Property            Value
00:00:00 00     origin_url          http://localhost:52531/
00:00:00 00     frame_url           http://localhost:52531/
00:00:00 00     frame_title         Home Page
00:00:00 00     url                 blob:http://localhost:52531/dcb25d89-9830-40a5-ba88-33c13b5c03eb
00:00:00 00     info                ChunkDemuxer: buffering by DTS
00:00:00 35     pipeline_state      kStarting
00:00:15 213    found_video_stream  true
00:00:15 213    video_codec_name    vp8
00:00:15 216    video_dds           false
00:00:15 216    video_decoder       FFmpegVideoDecoder
00:00:15 216    info                Selected FFmpegVideoDecoder for video decoding, config: codec: vp8 format: 1 profile: vp8 coded size: [1280,720] visible rect: [0,0,1280,720] natural size: [1280,720] has extra data? false encryption scheme: Unencrypted rotation: 0°
00:00:15 216    pipeline_state      kPlaying
00:00:15 213    duration            unknown
00:00:16 661    height              720
00:00:16 661    width               1280
00:00:16 665    video_buffering_state       BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
00:00:16 665    for_suspended_start         false
00:00:16 665    pipeline_buffering_state    BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
00:00:16 667    pipeline_state      kSuspending
00:00:16 670    pipeline_state      kSuspended
00:00:52 759    info                Effective playback rate changed from 0 to 1
00:00:52 759    event               PLAY
00:00:52 759    pipeline_state      kResuming
00:00:52 760    video_dds           false
00:00:52 760    video_decoder       FFmpegVideoDecoder
00:00:52 760    info                Selected FFmpegVideoDecoder for video decoding, config: codec: vp8 format: 1 profile: vp8 coded size: [1280,720] visible rect: [0,0,1280,720] natural size: [1280,720] has extra data? false encryption scheme: Unencrypted rotation: 0°
00:00:52 760    pipeline_state      kPlaying
00:00:52 793    height              720
00:00:52 793    width               1280
00:00:52 798    video_buffering_state       BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
00:00:52 798    for_suspended_start         false
00:00:52 798    pipeline_buffering_state    BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
00:00:56 278    video_buffering_state       BUFFERING_HAVE_NOTHING
00:00:56 295    for_suspended_start         false
00:00:56 295    pipeline_buffering_state    BUFFERING_HAVE_NOTHING
00:01:20 717    event               PAUSE
00:01:33 538    event               PLAY
00:01:35 94     event               PAUSE
00:01:55 561    pipeline_state      kSuspending
00:01:55 563    pipeline_state      kSuspended
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code, or dose chrome require some magic configuration to work?

Thanks~

Please excuse my english :)